# SQL #1064 Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is wrong with the following?

**Error**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(
>   `cp_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
>   `cp_model` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
>   `cp_name` VAR' at line 1

**SQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE `car_parts` (
 `cp_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `cp_model` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_image` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_cost` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_speed` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_control` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_power` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_available` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`car_parts`)
 ) TYPE=MYISAM ;
```

so i did what you lot said and now this is the error i get :(

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'TYPE=MYISAM' at line 12
```

Comment: seems like you have syntax error in ur query

Answer (score 5):

Based on analysis of your error message, you did not give your table a name. The proper syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
    `cp_id` INT NOT NULL,
    ......
);
```

You forgot the `` `tablename` `` part.

EDIT: Since you provided your full query, apparently my analysis was incorrect. Your mistake was putting `CREATE DATABASE` when you want `CREATE TABLE`.

EDIT2: On further analysis, you will encounter another problem: `auto_increment` fields MUST be defined as an index on your table. In general, your `auto_increment` column should be your `PRIMARY KEY`, not some arbitrary other column... and certainly not the table name. That just makes no sense.

Comment: Damn close you are ;D

Comment: CREATE TABLE `car_parts` (
 `cp_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `cp_model` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_image` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_cost` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_speed` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_control` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_power` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 `cp_available` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`car_parts`)
 ) TYPE=MYISAM ;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected <-- this error now

Comment: @xCowBoyx Then select a database - this should be a part of your connection string. Alternatively, try ``CREATE TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` ...``

Comment: @xCowBoyx you need to select which schema you are using... so run USE schema_name; Then your create table

Comment: Could someone Please Just Re-write it But The Fixed Way. i think ill understand then

Comment: @xCowBoyx what is the name of your schema?

Comment: @xCowBoyx http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0edd5

Comment: @xCowBoyx you cannot have an auto increment on a field that is not labeled the primary key so you either need to remove the autoincrement or make cp_id the primary key...